# List of integers to list of strings ANSIBLE

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, yaml

I am creating a task to run a AWS command like below:

```
- name: Disassociates all current members
  command: sh -c 'aws guardduty disassociate-members --account-ids "{{ member_ids }}" --detector-id "{{ detector_id }}" --region "{{ TARGET_AWS_REGION }}"'
  environment:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
  register: response
```

where **member_ids** is a list which comes from another command:

```
set_fact: 
    member_ids: "{{ (response.stdout | from_json).Members | map(attribute='AccountId') | list | to_json }}"
```

**member_ids**:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
"member_ids": [
    "123456789123", 
    "456654879899", 
    "654897987955"
]
```

}

But then I've got an error:

```
"Invalid type for parameter AccountIds[0], value: 123456789123, type: <type 'int'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>",
"Invalid type for parameter AccountIds[1], value: 456654879899, type: <type 'int'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>",
"Invalid type for parameter AccountIds[2], value: 654897987955, type: <type 'int'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>",
```

Which means the AWS command requires a list of strings. So how to cast all value in the **member_ids** list from int value to string value?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: try `"{{ member_ids|string }}"` ?

Comment: `map('string')`, but it is unclear where your error comes from. Ansible? `aws`?

Comment: Strange...Both doesn't work though, I'm still getting that error. The error comes from aws because that command requires a list of strings instead of a list of integers

Comment: Check `-vvv` output and see what is passed as command. You should use `to_json` filter inside `command`, and not inside `set_fact`.